# Is there an elegant way to correct common data-entry mistakes in Canadian postal codes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

An app I am working on gets Canadian addresses from a number of external sources and maps them.  A not uncommon source of mapping errors arises from data-entry mistakes in the postal code, ie, entering an uppercase o instead of a zero, an uppercase i instead of a one, and so on.

For the purpose of this question, assume all postal code data has had all whitespace removed, has been uppercased, and is truncated to 6 characters if longer than that.  In that case, a valid Canadian postal code would be in the format "A1A1A1".  What is an elegant way to make the replacements described above?

We have a working solution, but this has become an interesting question in our office, just to see what people come up with. So far, nothing that screams "awesome."

Some other conditions:

- If the postal code is invalid already (eg only 4 characters long) feel free to either update it or ignore it
- The replacements should work both ways, ie invalid letters should be converted to numbers, and invalid numbers should be converted to letters.
- It has to be done in ruby, because this is a rails app

Comment: Cant your mapping service correct for these errors? Google maps has a great API and bad data dosen't even phase it.

Comment: You sound like a person who would (given some skill) write a compiler that *guesses* the intent of the user, silently ignoring what's actually been written, errors or not...

Comment: @Devin:  Maybe, although we're being forced to use Bing, so who knows?  The point is really just to come up with an interesting answer to the problem

Comment: @Blindy: I assume the intent of the user is to get their address mapped correctly, and since I can't tell the user to enter the proper postal code, I am guessing they meant to enter it correctly

Comment: Well considering you can never know what the user intended and what type of error they made its nearly impossible to correct the input to what the user intended in an automated way. Your better off using fields like city and provence to figure the location out.

Comment: @Marc Blindy does have a point, you shouldnt try to bend a users input to your definition of what is correct. Maybe they missed the 3rd letter in or transposed a number and a digit. Perhaps that is a valid zip code but its for another area, what then?

Comment: You are correct if it's another format, but it's not.  A Canadian postal code MUST BE A1A1A1.  Anything else is wrong.  Therefore, trying to change AIA1A1 to A1A1A1 is a reasonable assumption, since the original is incorrect anyway.

Answer (score 3):

```
def clean_postal_code
  swaps = {'L' => '1', 'O' => '0'} #fill with whatever necessary substitutions
  pc = self.postal_code
  (pc.size/2).times do |n|
    swaps.each do |letter, number|
      pc[n*2+1] = pc[n*2+1].chr.gsub(letter, number) #only want numbers on odd indices
      pc[n*2] = pc[n*2].chr.gsub(number, letter) #only characters on even indices
    end
  end
  self.postal_code = pc
end
```

Comment: Readable and maintainable.  I like it.

Answer (score 3):

Similar to Tron's but (IMHO) a bit simpler and doesn't require the number-to-letter map to be symmetric:

```
chars = { '0' => 'O', '1' => 'I'             } # etc.
nums  = { 'O' => '0', 'I' => '1', 'Q' => '0' } # etc.
maps  = [
        ->(c) { chars[c.upcase] || c.upcase }, 
        ->(c) { nums[ c.upcase] || c }
]
clean = (0 ... input.length).map { |i| maps[i % 2].call(s[i]) }.join
```

You start with a dirty `input` and get `clean` as the fixed up version. For example, this will convert `'aib100'` to `'A1B1O0'`.

You could wrap it up in a function if desired:

```
def unmangle(input)
    chars = { '0' => 'O', '1' => 'I'             } # etc.
    nums  = { 'O' => '0', 'I' => '1', 'Q' => '0' } # etc.
    maps  = [
            ->(c) { chars[c.upcase] || c.upcase }, 
            ->(c) { nums[ c.upcase] || c }
    ]
    (0 ... input.length).map { |i| maps[i % 2].call(input[i]) }.join
end

clean = unmangle('aib100')
# 'A1B1O0'
```

You could also use this (or various other similar constructions):

```
(0 ... input.length).inject(input) { |s, i| s[i] = maps[i % 2].call(s[i]); s }
```

If you don't like the `map`/`join` version.

Answer (score 1):

I'm taking this as a bit of a *how compact can you make the code* challenge. I would NOT necessarily actually writing it like this - something like Tron's answer would likely be much more maintainable.

That said, something like this should in principle work:

```
def clean_pc(pc)
  pc.split(/(?<=\G..)/).map {|a| a[0].tr('01','OL') + a[1].tr('OoLliI','001111') }.join
end
```

(UPDATE)

... or, much easier to read, and probably maintainable enough for production use:

```
def clean_pc(pc)
  pc.chars.each_slice(2).map {|a| a[0].tr('01','OL') + a[1].tr('OoLliI','001111')}.join
end
```

Comment: Nice!  Thanks for getting in the spirit of it.

Comment: Thanks @Marc. Added a cleaner version that might do the job better. Thanks for sparking my interest!